# How to update Firefox offline to a specific version on Centos 6.9

Tags: centos, yum, rpm, firefox

I'm trying to install a specific version of Firefox (52.8) on Centos 6.9. I've used "yumdownload --resolve firefox...x86_64". It created a folder the firefox rpm as well as 5 or six other dependencies. These included nspr-4.19 and several nss-3.6 rpms.

When I tried to install it on another system (using rpm -ivh firefox..x86-64.rpm), it had a dependency conflict with existing nspr (a lower version). When I tried to uninstall the existing version, it said it would delete a bunch of important modules.

What's the best solution? Should I try to do an rpm update on the underlying modules? If so, do I specify the older one or the newer one?

Comment: Unfortunately, our software relies on a flash plugin. It doesn't work with Firefox 60, but does with 58.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass all dependencies to a `rpm -U` (or `yum install`) command -- not just the firefox RPM -- it should satisfy the requirements for `nspr`, etc. for other packages on the system. This will not work, however, if other packages depend on a specific version of `nspr`.

```
cd /path/to/downloaded/rpms
yum install *.rpm
```

Answer (score 0):

What about downloading and running firefox binary without installing to system?

https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/